# Magento 2 - Image Label returning Product name

Tags: magento2

I am trying to display a `Product Image` but am not able to get the correct data for the `Alt Text`

`$image = $block->getImage($_product, 'category_page_grid');`

When I call `$image->getLabel()` it is returning the name of the `Product` rather than the `Alt Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to call  `addMediaGalleryData()` if you want to get the `Alt` information.

```
$items = $block->getProductCollection()->addMediaGalleryData()->getItems();
foreach($items as $_product){
    $values = ($_product->getMediaAttributeValues());
    $images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
}
```

I could not find a way to get the `Alt` value when calling

`$image = $block->getImage($product, 'category_page_grid')`

Though I could loop through the `$images` and reference the image name that matched `$image` and get the `Alt` value from there.

Answer (score 0):

That question has been answered similarly on Stackexchange: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210995/media-image-attribute-width-height-and-alt-tag-in-a-phtml-magento-2

Use this and call `$image->getAttribute('alt')`